# Alerts via email for stocks, FX prices

Tags: email, notification

I am looking for a software or web service that can send alerts to me via email. I know, there are dozens (or more) such free services. But I am looking for one simple service that allows me to insert stock details from a website, FX prices and possibly set price alerts for both. 
If you have any software/web service to recommend, I can pay too.